# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am new to Python and I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong - I would like to ask a user for three numbers and print their sum, here's my current code:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    total = None
    num = input('Please enter number {}:'.format(str(i)))
    total += num
```

By the way, the total = None was to try and declare the variable so I could use it without setting a value?
I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 4, in <module>
    total += num
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: `total = None`, excuse me?

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `None` and `0` is? Do you know what the difference between `'0'` and `0` is?

Comment: '0' would be a string, 0 would be a number/int

Comment: As is currently written, I doubt the code would run without getting a `IndentationError`.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation, I guess it automatically indents in the python shell but won't copy it? I have added the indentation anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do `total = None`. `NoneType` cannot be used against addition.

There's an extra problem suggested by the error message: From your description you're trying to add 3 **numbers**, but the return type of the builtin `input()` is `str`. So this is what you're supposed to write:

```
total = 0
for i in range(0, 3):
    num = input('Please enter number {}:'.format(str(i)))
    total += int(num)
```

All the points:

- Indent the code correctly. Indentation is a *crucial* part of Python.
- Don't set `total` to zero at every loop. Only set it once outside the loop
- Take care of types

Comment: When I run this and try to print(total) it just returns the last number instead of all them added together

Comment: I am doing something very similar, and this is only the code I already had that threw the error.