# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, int, nonetype

I am a begginer in Python and I can not find the mistake in this code bellow. Do you know how I can fix it? Thanks!

```
import fileinput
import time
pat = "hello"
cout = 0

with fileinput.input(files=('packet.txt')) as f:
    for line in f:
            start_time = time.time()
            val = search(txt, pat)
            end_time = time.time()
            run_time = (end_time - start_time)*1000000
            if(val == -1):
                print("No Text")
                run_time = (end_time - start_time)*1000000
                #print(" ---> Processing time: "'{0:.3f}'.format(run_time),  "microseconds")
                print(" ---> Processing time: "'{0:.3f}'.format(run_time),  "microseconds")
            else:
                val = val + 1
                print ('Pattern \"' + pat + '\" found at position',val + count)
                run_time = (end_time - start_time)*1000000
                print(" ---> Processing time: "'{0:.3f}'.format(run_time),  "microseconds")
```

TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()

```
     16   print(" ---> Processing time: ",'{0:.3f}'.format(run_time),  "microseconds")
     17             else:
```

```
---> 18                     val = val + 1


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Before adding `1` to `val` you should check it's not `None` (`if val is not None:`)

Comment: What does your `search()` function look like? Is it returning something? Also where is `txt` defined?

Comment: Presumably, your `search` function returns `None`. Why that is the case we cannot say without a [mcve]

Comment: Similar questions have been asked hundreds of times. What have you done to resolve this? Had you done any research? Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110282/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22762078/11301900, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48486205/11301900, ...

Comment: Oh and it seems like you're using `re.search()`, which can return `None`, not -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `search()` function returns `None` when it can't find the pattern, not `-1`. So change

```
if val == -1:
```

to

```
if val is None:
```